# Error : invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF-8" while Importing csv into postgresql using copy from command

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to load csv file into postgresql db which is in utf-8 format.
when I use `file -i <file_name.csv>`, it is giving the result as `application/octet-stream; charset=binary`, so when I'm trying to load it using **COPY FROM** command it is giving an error as
`invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF-8"`

here is my copy command :

```
String copyQuery="COPY "+tableName+"("+columns+") FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER'"+this.delimit+"' CSV HEADER";
```

Tried ENCODING 'UTF-8' and resulted the same.

How do I over come this issue??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is csv-file readable at all? Are you sure it's not compressed or encrypted? Did you saw that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304178/235083 ? Maybe it answers your question?

Comment: Yes, it is readable

Comment: So: maybe it's UTF-16LE? Did you tried `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8` ?

Comment: I tried it but not able to import data to database